# Is it possible to connect to an external API for a response using Google Actions API (or another service)?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I have recently been wanting to create a Google Assistant application to read me information from an API (that I have created). I have been doing some research and found that IFTTT AFAIK, but then I came across the Google Actions API. So my question is: Is it possible to do this with the Google Actions, or can I use something else? *See diagram below.* Sorry for my bad diagram skills, hope it is understandable.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIdJ2.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, but the question is about the security and the authentication to your API. how is it  managed? Is Google Assistant compliant with it?

Comment: Do you want to integrate with IFTTT, create a smart home action, or something else?

Comment: @NickFelker No, I tried to use IFTTT but it only supports you asking the assistant a phrase then it doing something you can't get a response from a API and send it to the Google Home, AFAIK on the free plan.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I haven't created the API yet, it can use authentication ore be open. This shouldn't be a problem since I should be able to implement this for the code of the my Google action right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion in the comments, you want to build [a conversational action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/build) which lets you invoke your action ie. "Talk to my test app", give your action a query, then use [a webhook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=sdk) to make an API call and return a spoken response on your speaker.